# Non Bool in if statement / Obj-C closures in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've been trying to convert the tutorial https://github.com/fastred/CustomScrollView from Objective-C to Swift but I'm stuck in a few places.

In Objective-C it has the properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIDynamicItemBehavior *decelerationBehavior;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIAttachmentBehavior *springBehavior;
```

and then it has the if statement:

```
if self.decelerationBehavior && !self.springBehavior { ... }
```

Since these are clearly no `Bool`'s, what does this mean in Swift?

---

```
void(^solveForY)(CGPoint*) = ^(CGPoint *anchor) {
    if (deltaY != 0) {
        anchor->y = a * anchor->x + b;
    }
};
```

This one seems to be a closure and I've tried converting it to Swift using:

```
func solveForY(_ anchor: inout CGPoint) { if deltaY != 0 { anchor.y = a * anchor.x + b } }
```

---

```
__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

decelerationBehavior.action = ^{
    CGRect bounds = weakSelf.bounds;
    bounds.origin = weakSelf.dynamicItem.center;
    weakSelf.bounds = bounds;
};
```

---

But the converted app doesn't behave like the original at all. Can someone tell me how to convert this to Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting all that correctly, here's how I would do it in Swift:

```
var decelerationBehavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior?
var springBehavior: UIAttachmentBehavior?

// the if statement in Objective-C is checking for nil. In Objective-C nil == 0 == false
if let decelerationBehavior = decelerationBehavior, let springBehavior = springBehavior { ... }

let solveForY: (CGPoint) -> () = { (anchor) in
    if deltaY != 0 {
        anchor.y = a * anchor.x + b;
    }
}

decelerationBehavior.action = { [weak self] in
    if let weakSelf = self {
        CGRect bounds = weakSelf.bounds
        bounds.origin = weakSelf.dynamicItem.center
        weakSelf.bounds = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm starting to understand why some ppl call Objc-C alien language.. :o. I've added one more tiny closure. I just can't seem to convert the app and make it work... so frustrating :(

Comment: Haha Swift is very different, but in a lot of ways Obj-C is fairly similar to other C based languages, just with some different syntax. Added the other closure to the answer.

Comment: Tx a bunch again. Probably will take a whole lot of time to figure out how to get it to work in Swift :)